# If you were to introduce a new charge into the universe, would the electric field at all points in space emerge instantaneously?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

To elaborate, let's say you only have one charged particle existing in the universe. If you were to introduce another charged particle into the universe without applying any other forces, would these particles begin to accelerate instantaneously?

Comment: You cannot introduce "new charges" in physics in this way, therefore physics cannot answer this question.

Comment: You can, however, produce new dipoles.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, interesting that physics cannot answer this question, yet riemanntensor did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: As many people have pointed out, my old answer does not exactly work, because the scenario posted by the OP cannot be explained by physical laws.

However, I'm going to answer a different question now, which I think was what the OP was looking for anyway. If you initially have a distribution of charges, and you move a few around or make changes to it in a way not violating the conservation of charge, any changes to the electromagnetic field (such as moving one charge from one location to another) propagate at the speed of light, so any resulting acceleration is not felt instantaneously.

Comment: This is the answer to my question. I just wasn't sure how to ask. Thanks!

Comment: This is wrong. *Moreover, any changes to the electromagnetic field (such as moving one charge from one location to another) propagate at the speed of light, so any resulting acceleration is not felt instantaneously.* But the OP isn't asking about moving a charge, the OP is asking about violating charge conservation by creating a charge. This makes Maxwell's equations false, so we can't use Maxwell's equations to make predictions about the propagation of signals.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now. I guess I was trying to answer a question for which no physical answer was possible.